# Insert a list whithout spaces between each index in a entry widget tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

`my_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']`
When I print this list without spaces I use `print(*my_list, sep="")`
and it prints `12345` (instead of `1 2 3 4 5`)

I need to insert my_list in an Entry widget in Tkinter but when I do `my_entry.insert(0, my_list)`
of course, the output is `1 2 3 4 5`
but I need it to be without spaces in between the items in my_list.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the elements of a list together using something like:

```
''.join(my_list)
```

which returns the string created by joining the list elements, allowing you to do:

```
my_entry.insert(0, ''.join(my_list))
```

Comment: when i change from ```my_entry.insert(0, my_list)``` to ```my_entry.join(my_list)``` i get AttributeError:  'Entry' object has no attribute 'join'.

Comment: `join` is a function on strings, not Entry objects. You would do something like `my_entry.insert(0, ''.join(my_list))`. I've updated the answer to be clearer on that.